# Dynamic rtmp streaming with jwplayer

Tags: javascript, php, stream, jwplayer, wowza

I am trying to publish dynamic RTMP stream with javascript and php.

I want to get stream name from url and publish the stream on my web player (jwplayer)
like `xxx.com/watch.php?chanel=music`

I want to use the music as my stream name and want to show the stream with my jwplayer. Suppose my  rtmp hosting is `rtmp://xx.yy.zz.yy:1987/live`

Now I want to get the stream name music from the url and publish the full stream `rtmp://xx.yy.zz.yy:1987/live/music` through jwplayer dynamically.

if someone hit xxx.com/watch.php?chanel=sports he will able to see `rtmp://xx.yy.zz.yy:1987/live/sports` stream.

I wrote the following script but its not working

```
<?php
include ("template/header.html");
?>
<div class="container-fluid">
<script src="stream/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="mediaplayer">This div will be replaced by the JW Player</div>
<script>

<script>
var chanel = getQueryVariable("chanel");

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 

}
var host= ("rtmp://216.245.200.114/Live/");
var stream=host.concat(chanel);
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
width: "600",
height: "500",
primary: "flash",
autostart: "true",
repeat: 'always',
sources:[
{   file: stream    }
]
});
</script>
</div>
<?php
include ("template/footer.html");
?>
```

Now when I am hitting the http://www.justlive24.com/watch.php?chanel=shomoy its not loading the player. I am newbie and trying to find out the solution. Your brief explanation will help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've syntax error: 
1. http://joxi.ru/nvGdUxjKTJBNH3ESafE
2. http://joxi.ru/yPGdU_3JTJA7Y4XfP7M
also some fixes todo...

try this code: http://pastebin.com/UzhuVpXm

don't forget to attach jquery between head tags

Comment: thanks a lot for fixing my issues. I am absolutely new so that i did some silly mistakes. Thanks for fixing it. its now working.

Comment: nice. happy to help (:

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
include ("template/header.html");
?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="stream/jwplayer.js"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="mediaplayer">This div will be replaced by the JW Player</div>
        <script>
            function getQueryVariable(variable) {
                var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var vars = query.split("&");
                for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                    if (pair[0] == variable) {
                        return pair[1];
                    }
                }
                return '';
            }
            $(function(){
                var chanel = getQueryVariable("chanel");
                var host= "rtmp://216.245.200.114/Live/";
                var stream=host+chanel;
                jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
                    width: "600",
                    height: "500",
                    primary: "flash",
                    autostart: "true",
                    repeat: 'always',
                    sources:[
                        {   file: stream    }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
<?php
include ("template/footer.html");
?>
```