# Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm not sure why i'm getting the following error. Can you please suggest what change in my code needed to successfully play the rtmp stream on my stage?
**error:**

> NetConnection.Connect.Success Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:.
>   level=error, code=NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound   at
>   main/attachnetstream()[/Users/user/Desktop/ojotha/main.as:24] Debug
>   session terminated.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;

    public class main extends MovieClip {
    public var streamserver:String="rtmp://216.245.200.114/live";
    public var streamname:String="shomoy";
    public var netconnection:NetConnection=new NetConnection();

        public function main() {
            netconnection.connect(streamserver);
            netconnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, attachnetstream);




        }
        public function attachnetstream(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
            trace(event.info.code);
            switch (event.info.code) {
                case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                var netstream:NetStream=new NetStream(netconnection);
                var video:Video=new Video();
                video.attachNetStream(netstream);
                netstream.play(streamname);
                video.height=480;
                video.width=640;
                addChild(video);

                break;
                case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                trace("stream not found");
                break;
            }
                }


            }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try `rtmp://216.245.200.114/live/` I mean with ending slash, I had same issue time ago and that solved it

Comment: see this also may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233131/dynamic-rtmp-streaming-with-jwplayer

Comment: i've tryied usig the slash but same result :
Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
 at main/attachnetstream()[/Users/user/Desktop/ojotha/main.as:25]
Debug session terminated.

Comment: Just to say.. Make sure there is actually a stream being broadcast. Server URL alone is not enough. What do you expect to see if the stream was connected (found)? Test it here [ [Wowza RTMP Tester](http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.5.0/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html) ] also. You can first try **Server** = `rtmp://cp79650.live.edgefcs.net/live/` and **Stream** = `QVCLive1@14308 ` if it works now try yours. Maybe your code is fine but its just a server / broadcast issue?

Answer (score -1):

You should add NetStatusEvent event listener to your stream as well.

```
stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
```

Look at the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html)

You may also need to set another event listener, even if it is empty to prevent some other runtime errors.

```
stream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
```